# Animate itemize but not subitemize with beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

I would like to do the opposite of what is in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44666/63689). That is, I would like an itemize environment to be animated, but I don't want the subitems to be animated.

The result should be as follows. 
First slide :

```
item 1
```

Second slide :

```
item 1
item 2
item 2.1
item 2.2
```

Third slide :

```
item 1
item 2
item 2.1
item 2.2
item 3
```

I also don't want to have to specify the exact slide on which different items appear, and would like something akin to the `[<+->]` option. For the moment, I have the following code, which animates the subitems.

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item item 1
    \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 2.1
        \item item 2.2
    \end{itemize}
    \item item 3
\end{itemize}
```

How can I get the subitems to all show at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use  `<.->`, i quote the page 93 of the manual :

> There is another special sign you can use in an overlay specification that behaves similarly to the `+-`sign: a dot. When you write `<.->`, a similar thing as in `<+->` happens except that the counter beamerpauses is not incremented and except that you get the value of beamerpauses decreased by one.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item item 1
    \item Item 2
    \begin{itemize}[<.->]
        \item item 2.1
        \item item 2.2
    \end{itemize}
    \item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> item 1
\item<2-> item 2
\begin{itemize}
\item item 2.1
\item item 2.2
\end{itemize}
\item<3-> item 3
\end{itemize}
```